# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

views.py

```
def when(request):
    user = request.user  
    try:
        report = Report.objects.get(user=user.id)
    except:
        report = None
    settings = Settings.objects.get(user=request.user)
    settingsForm = SettingsForm(instance=settings)
    if settings.date_format == '0':
        date = report.manual_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')             
    else:
        date = report.manual_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')        
       reportform = ReportForm(instance=report)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reportform = ReportForm(request.POST,instance=report)
        if reportform.is_valid():
            report = reportform.save(commit=False)
            report.user = request.user
            report.save()
            return redirect('/member/media/')
    reportform = ReportForm(instance=report,initial={'manual_date':date})
```

The above code is used to convert and show the date format.Initially,i hard coded the value in database and checked about format change.Now,for 1st time,for new record in database,it is giving this error "`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strftime'`"

I don't know how to logically handle this.Need your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to handle the check for both `report` and  `report.manual_date` for `None`

Try this:

```
def when(request):
    user = request.user
    date = None  
    try:
        report = Report.objects.get(user=user)
    except:
        report = None
    settings = Settings.objects.get(user=user)
    settingsForm = SettingsForm(instance=settings)
    reportform = ReportForm()
    if report and report.manual_date:
        if settings.date_format == '0':
            date = report.manual_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')             
        else:
            date = report.manual_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')        
        reportform = ReportForm(instance=report)

    if request.method == 'POST':            
        reportform = ReportForm(request.POST)
        if report:
            reportform = ReportForm(request.POST,instance=report)

        if reportform.is_valid():
            report = reportform.save(commit=False)
            report.user = request.user
            report.save()
            return redirect('/member/media/')
    reportform = ReportForm(instance=report,initial={'manual_date':date})
```

Comment: "Most likely your report object is None".  No.  If that were the case, the error message would say "NoneType object has no attribute manual_date".

Comment: thanks.. but the code would not work if report is None anyways.. I edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to logically handle this

```
manual_date = report.manual_date

if (manual_date):
    format =  (settings.date_format == "0") ? '%d/%m/%Y' : '%m/%d/%Y'
    date = manual_date.strftime(format)

else:
   #No report.manual_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) function:

```
def when(request):
    user = request.user  
    report = get_object_or_404(Report, user=user) #no need to use the id
    settings = get_object_or_404(Settings, user=user)
    settingsForm = SettingsForm(instance=settings)
    if settings.date_format == '0':
        date = report.manual_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')             
    else:
        date = report.manual_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')        
       reportform = ReportForm(instance=report)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reportform = ReportForm(request.POST,instance=report)
        if reportform.is_valid():
            report = reportform.save(commit=False)
            report.user = request.user
            report.save()
            return redirect('/member/media/')
    reportform = ReportForm(instance=report,initial={'manual_date':date})
```